# Как запустить компьютер?

Tags: windows

Как запустить компьютер??? Если помыл его с мылом от вирусов но он перестал запускаться

Comment: `можно на русском` — тут на других нельзя ;)

Comment: Кст твой вопрос немного неясен. Имеешь в виду ANSI или что?

Comment: что за cmd?....

Comment: Совсем  не ясно что нужно, поэтому "Закрыть" до момента пока не появится больше деталей и уточнений

Comment: @АлексейШиманский командная строка в винде

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov на javascript?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хм, про js не заметил. возможно, автор имел в виду консоль в инструментах разработчика браузера...

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov вот поэтому и закрыть до "выяснения обстоятельств"

Comment: из js вывести в cmd сообщение чтоб не повторялось

Comment: @user15091863 а в каких случаях оно повторяется?

Comment: Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой первый вопрос, а не пишите новые в месте для ответов. И, пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать так, чтобы вас можно было понять. Желательно, с точками и запятыми. Пока не ясно даже, имеется в виду консоль браузера или системная консоль, JS выполняется в браузере или в Node.js, ваша проблема в частоте вывода или в цвете...

Answer (score 5):

Оно?

```js
let styles = [
    'background: red',
    'background: orange',
    'background: gold',
    'background: yellowgreen',
    'background: skyblue',
    'background: steelblue',
    'background: darkviolet'
];

console.log ( '%c R %c A %c I %c N %c B %c O %c W ', ...styles );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если в сообщении написать `%c`, то следующий за ним текст будет выведен с таким стилем, который будет указан в следующем параметре после строки с спецсимволом. Если таких символов много - то можно после строки можно указать через запятую несколько стилей для каждого из этих символов (см. пример выше)

Примеры:

```js
console.log('%c test', 'color: red');

console.log('%c test-red %c test-green', 'color: red', 'color: green');

console.log('%c test-red %c test-green %c test-blue', 'color: red', 'color: green', 'color: blue');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Также можно не указывать текст сразу после символа `%c`, а можно поставить `%s` и так же вместо него подставить данные впоследствии.

```js
console.log('%c%s','color: green; background: yellow; font-size: 24px;','Success!');

console.log('%c%s %c%s','color: green;', 'Success!', 'color:red', 'Error!');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]